# Magento 2 Store Configuration Fields not Showing updated Data

Tags: magento2, configuration, magento-2.2.5

I am having an issue. When I update/save data in Store configuration, then it get's updated in the database, but on admin panel, it's not getting changed.

It's urgent so please help me with this.

TIA

Comment: Magento 2.2 has option to dump store configuration to the config.php file. Check if this feature is active. If so, edit from BE can work not 100% correctly

Comment: will it update the data that is being shown on admin panel? @K.Maliszewski

Answer (score 1):

It may be due to the file

> app/etc/config.php

You can specify the configuration of the store in this file. Review it y check if you have any setting here.

Here more information https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-config-mgmt-import.html